Difficulty Solving Large Multi-Rod System with NDSolve - Seeking Advice on Handling Complex Lagrange Equations
I'm currently working on a system involving connected rods, each linked by torsional springs. The system has a general structure as shown in the diagram below: there are n rods connected in series, with each rod linked by a spring that governs the relative torsion between them. At one rod in the system, I'm applying a time-varying torque, M(t), as indicated in the diagram.
I've successfully derived the Lagrange equations for the system, which results in a set of coupled second-order differential equations. The problem arises when I attempt to numerically solve these equations in Mathematica using NDSolve. When n is small, the solver works well, and the numerical solutions match with the theoretical expectations. However, my goal is to solve the system for a much larger n, ideally around 50, and this is where NDSolve fails to converge, often throwing errors related to stiffness or other reasons.
I suspect the system's complexity increases dramatically with the number of rods, leading to numerical instabilities or stiffness that NDSolve struggles with. Given that the equations are derived from Lagrange mechanics, they inherently have a lot of coupled dynamics, which might be causing issues for NDSolve's default algorithms.
My questions are:
How can I improve the stability and efficiency of NDSolve for such a large coupled system? Are there specific methods or options that I should try tweaking, such as Method settings or stiffness handling?
Are there alternative approaches in Mathematica for solving large systems of coupled second-order differential equations more effectively? For example, would breaking the problem into smaller components or using different formulations (e.g., state-space representation) help here?
Has anyone dealt with similarly large mechanical systems? Any general tips for improving the performance of numerical solvers in such situations would be greatly appreciated.
The attached diagram illustrates the basic structure, with  being applied at a specific point to induce motion in the system. Any insights on managing the complexity of this problem, or how to optimize the numerical solution process in Mathematica, would be very helpful.

And here is the code I used
(*Parameter definitions*)
n = 4; (*Number of rods,can be modified as needed*)
p = 2; (*Rod number where external torque is applied*)
m = 1; (*Mass*)
Ltotal = 1; (*Total length*)
l = Ltotal/n; (*Length of each rod element*)
kt = 1; (*Torsional stiffness*)
kd = 0; (*Damping coefficient*)
Tfin = 10; (*Total time*)
freq = 1; (*Load frequency*)
MM = 1/10*Sin[2*Pi*freq*t]; (*External torque*)

(*Definition of generalized coordinates and generalized velocities*)
q = Table[
   Subscript[\[Theta], i][t], {i, 1, 
    n}]; (*Generalized coordinates,representing the rotation angle of \
each rod*)
qd = Table[
   D[Subscript[\[Theta], i][t], t], {i, 1, 
    n}]; (*Generalized velocities,representing the angular velocity \
of each rod*)

(*Definition of the position and velocity of the center of mass of \
each rod (calculated through node positions)*)
nodePositions = Table[{}, {n + 1}];
nodePositions[[1]] = {0, 0}; (*Initial node position*)

Do[nodePositions[[i + 1]] = 
   nodePositions[[i]] + l*{Cos[q[[i]]], Sin[q[[i]]]}, {i, 1, n}];

(*Center of mass is located at the midpoint of each rod*)
positions = 
  Table[(nodePositions[[i]] + nodePositions[[i + 1]])/2, {i, 1, n}];
velocities = Table[D[positions[[i]], t], {i, 1, n}];

(*Definition of kinetic energy for each rod (including translational \
and rotational components)*)
T = Sum[(1/2)*m*(velocities[[i]] . velocities[[i]]) + 
    1/2*(1/12*m*l^2)*qd[[i]]^2, {i, 1, 
    n}]; (*Total kinetic energy:translational kinetic \
energy+rotational kinetic energy*)

(*Definition of potential energy (including only elastic potential \
energy,no gravitational term)*)
V = Sum[(1/2)*kt*(q[[i + 1]] - q[[i]])^2, {i, 1, n - 1}] + (1/2)*
    kt*(q[[1]])^2; (*Elastic potential energy*)

(*Lagrangian function*)
L = T - V;

(*Lagrange equations*)
lagrangeEquations = 
  Table[D[D[L, qd[[i]]], t] - D[L, q[[i]]] == 
    If[i == p, MM, 0] - kd*qd[[i]], {i, 1, n}];

(*Calculate Lagrange equations*)
sol = Simplify[lagrangeEquations];
initialConditions = 
  Flatten[{Table[(q /. t -> 0)[[i]] == 0, {i, 1, n}], 
    Table[(qd /. t -> 0)[[i]] == 0, {i, 1, n}]}];

solution = 
  NDSolve[Join[sol, initialConditions], q, {t, 0, Tfin}, 
   Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> "ExplicitEuler"}];
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[Flatten[nodePositions /. solution, 1] /. {t -> p}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, Ltotal}, {-Ltotal/20, Ltotal/20}}], {p, 0, Tfin}]

Thank you in advance for your time and suggestions!

I tried you well organised configuration with 50 rods it failed. However, Mathematica suggested "Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}" , This worked fine. Took 23 seconds on my machine in Version 14.1,

I should have added that I removed the Simplify. This takes a long time and does not help NDSolve.

@Hugh Thanks so much for your comment! Your method works well for me too, and I agree that it could be a solid answer to the question. However, since I believe this type of problem might be common in mechanics, I’d like to keep the question open a bit longer to see if any more innovative approaches come up.

modified T
Here my approach, perhaps a bit simpler and hopefully straight forward
(*Parameter definitions*)
n = 4;(*Number of rods,can be modified as needed*)
p = 2;(*Rod number where external torque is applied*)
m = 1;(*Mass*)
Ltotal = 1;(*Total length*)
l = Ltotal/n;(*Length of each rod element*)
kt = 1;(*Torsional stiffness*)
kd = 0;(*Damping coefficient*)
Tfin = 10;(*Total time*)
freq = 1;(*Load frequency*)
MM = 1/10*Sin[2*Pi*freq*t](*External torque*)

e = {Cos[#], Sin[#]} &; (* direction vector*)
var = Table[ToExpression["\[Theta]" <> ToString[i]][t], {i, 1, n}](* unknowns*)
pts[1] = l e[var[[1]]] (* n points*)
pts[i_] := pts[i - 1] + l e[var[[i]]]

T = Sum[Integrate[m/l/2 # . # &[D[pts[i] - xsi e[var[[i]]], t]], {xsi, 0,l}], {i, 1,n}] (*  modified  *)
V = 1/2 kt (var[[1]]'[t] + # . # &[Differences[var]])
lagrange = T - V;
Q = -kd D[var, t]; (* generalized forces*)
Q[[p]] = Q[[p]] + MM ;

ode = D[D[lagrange, {D[var, t]}], t] - D[lagrange, {var}] - Q ;
ic = Join[Map[# == 0 &, var], Map[# == 0 &, D[var, t]]] /. t -> 0;
sol = NDSolveValue[{ Map[# == 0 &, ode], ic} , var, {t, 0, Tfin}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];
sol\[Theta] = MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {var, sol}]

linie = Function[t,Evaluate[Join[{{0, 0}}, Table[pts[i], {i, 1, n}] /. sol\[Theta]]]];
Manipulate[
Graphics[{Line[linie[t]], Point[linie[t]]},PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-.1,.1}}], {{t, Tfin/2}, 0, Tfin, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]


